# Get changes on a list not working pnp-js Node Azure Function

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, pnp-js

Wondering if anyone else has an issue with the ["@pnp/sp/lists" getChanges](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/#get-changes-on-a-list) method. The following will not return any changes in my Node Azure Function:

```
const changeQuery: IChangeQuery = {
    Add: true,
    ChangeTokenEnd: null,
    ChangeTokenStart: null,
    DeleteObject: true,
    Rename: true,
    Restore: true,
    Update: true
};
const changes = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My Library").getChanges(changeQuery);
```

The following PowerShell does return changes

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity 'Bamert AP Documents'
$cq = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeQuery($true,$true)
$changes=$list.GetChanges($cq)
$list.Context.Load($changes)
$list.Context.ExecuteQuery()
$changes.count
#returns 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I was missing the Item property.  The correct IChangeQuery parameter should be:

```
const changeQuery: IChangeQuery = {
    Add: true,
    ChangeTokenEnd: null,
    ChangeTokenStart: null,
    DeleteObject: true,
    Rename: true,
    Restore: true,
    Update: true,
    Item:true
};
```

which includes `Item: true`